# How do you call ansible-playbook from Azure?

Tags: azure, ansible

How do you call an `ansible-playbook` from within Azure? Where is the command run from?

I have Ansible installed on a VM in Azure, and host I want to configure is located on a VM in our resource group.
I can log into that machine and call ansible-playbook from the command line.
But how can i call ansible-playbook remotely, from outside of that ansible machine?

Is there a best practice?
Can anyone provide me any examples?

Comment: This might be interesting: [Ansible Playbooks for Azure](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ansible-playbooks). This repository contains examples and best practices for building Ansible Playbooks for Azure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an option to configure it in [Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/getting-started-cloud-shell).

Another possibility would be to deploy another host. And simply install Ansible on that machine.

Comment: I already have Ansible installed on another host.I have updated the question to make that more apparent. Can cloud shell target my ansible machine directly and run playbooks on demand? Thanks for your help